# What does the word "concat" actually or originally mean?

Tags: java, concatenation

Recently I am reading a copy of source code from somewhere written in Java.

There's a statement of a method likes:

```
public static <T> List<T> concat(List<T>... lists){
    ...
}
```

and I wonder that whether it's suitable to name it "concat"? Originally, what does the word "concat" mean? Does it mean "CONnect ChAracTer" or other?

Comment: it means concatenate

Answer (score 7):

"concat" is short for "concatenate".

Comment: Thanks. Now I know it's suitable to name the method.

Answer (score 4):

As already said, *concat* stands for *concatenate*. As a former latinist, I recognize two parts here:

- *con* (cum), which means "with", "together"
- *catena*, which means "chain"

*Concatenate* thus means literally "put two chains together". What's interesting is that the French word for *String (of characters)* (French mainly comes from latin) is *Chaine (de caractères)*, which is the same word as the one used to say *Chain* in French.

Comment: +1 - Anyone who understands Latin deserves an upvote.  Too much information is never enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

It means that you're joining multiple values together to a new value. See String.concat to join two strings into one.

Shortened to `concat`, [Reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concatenate) defines `concatenate` as

> to link together; unite in a series or chain.

So basically everything which joins several values can be named value. So this function, if it joins multiple Lists, may be named concat. Merge as name would be possible, but implies that those values from all lists are sorted in some way while they're joined.

Answer (score 0):

The signature seems to define a method which accepts one or more `List` objects and returns just one `List`. The way I see it, `concat` means `concatenate`, meaning that it will attach one list to another thus yielding one larger list containing the elements of all the lists which where passed as method parameters.